# How come Getopt only excute into the if statement?

Tags: c, getopt

I'm using getopt to parse parameters from the terminal, it is been a pain in the back side for me.

This c program calculates a fibonacci sequence by getting a lower and upper limit, the command can either be given as: `./run -l 0 -u 100` (`-l` for lower limit, `-u` for upper limit) or `./run -l 0 100`. The string "-u" (upper limit is an optional parameter, the code have to handle both cases when "-u" is given or when only the value of the upper limit is given)

The program will always go into the if statement checking for when -v isn't given, even if i gave it -v in the command.

Source code below:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

int L_flag = 0;
int U_flag = 0;
int lower_limit;
int upper_limit;
int c;

// when no -u was given from input
if (argv[2][0] != '-'){
lower_limit = atoi (argv[2]);
upper_limit = atoi (argv[3]);
printf("lower_limit without -v: %d\n", lower_limit);
printf("upper_limit without -v: %d\n", upper_limit);
optind = 3;
}

//When -u is given
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "l:u")) != -1){
        switch (c){
        case 'l':
            L_flag = 1;
            lower_limit = atoi (optarg);
                        printf("here1: %d\n", lower_limit);
            break;
        case 'u':
            U_flag = 1;
            upper_limit = atoi (optarg);
                        printf("here1: %d\n", upper_limit);
                        break;
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that when `./run -l 0 100`, `argv[0]` is `"./run"`, `argv[1]` is `"-l"`, `argv[2]` is `"0"` and `argv[3]` is `"100"`.

Comment: Fixed, but still didn't solve the problem tho.

Comment: But you still check for `if (argv[2][0] != '-')`

Comment: @ when ./run -l 0 -u 100 is given, argv 0 is argv[0] is "./run", argv[1] is "-l", argv[2] is "-v" and argv[3] is "0", argv[4] is 100. Isn't this correct?

Comment: No. `argv[2]` is `"0"`. In both your examples `argv[2]` is `"0"`. How can you distinguish between them by checking for `argv[2][0]`?

Comment: @ timrau, getopts will parse strings before numbers, in the ./run -l 0 -u 100 example argv[2] is not 0 but "-v".

Comment: But `getopt()` haven't kick in when `if (argv[2][0] != '-')` was evaluated.

Comment: So i tried changing if (argv[2][0] != '-') to if (argv[3][0] = '-'), it seems have moved into the while loop now, but created a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

Besides checking for

```
if (argv[3][0] != '-')
```

to distinguish between the two scenarios, you should also change your call to `getopt()` into

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "l:u:")) != -1) {
```

to get the correct parameter after `-u`.

Comment: this fails to handle the '-v' parameter

Comment: the '-u' might not be included, while its' value is included (the upperLimit value).  in general, getopt will have difficulties when the '-x' part of a command line option is itself optional

Answer (score 0):

It would have been nice if the meaning of '-v' was mentioned and if the code is to force a specific ordering of the parameters.

in any case, given the example: './run -l 0 -u 100'

```
argv[0] is a pointer to the string "./run"
argv[1] is a pointer to the string "-l"
argv[2] is a pointer to the string "0"
argv[3] is a pointer to the string "-u"
argv[4] is a pointer to the string "100"
argv[5] is a NULL pointer

However, the specific string pointed to by argv[x] 
(other than argv[0])
varies depending on what the user actually input

suggest something like:

if( 1 >= argc )
{ 
    // handle error and exit
}


for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
{

    if ( argv[i][0] == '-' )
    { // then option found
        switch( argv[i][1] )
        {
            case 'v':
                break;

            case 'l':
                i++;
                lowerLimit = atoi( argv[i] );
                break;

            case 'u':
                i++;
                upperLimit = atoi( argv[i] );
                break;

            default:
                printf( "\ninvalid parameter: %s\n", argv[i] );
                break;
        } // end switch
    }
    else
    { // else argument with no leading identifier, assume upper limit
         upperLimit = atoi( argv[i] );
    } // end if
} // end for
```

This is not quite as robust as using getopt(), but will do the job